# Best solution for printing forms silently in windows application

Tags: c#, printing

I need to develop an application which prints forms. The initial plan is to create this application as desktop application in windows. The print should be silent without prompting anything and it should be too fast. So my concern is about the format of the document or document type(word,pdf etc.) If I use pdf or something it will initially open up in pdf reader and then print. When I searched, I got pcl files. SO now my question is pcl is the exact format for printing or is there anything better that this?.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PrintDocument class from System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument,here is example I have tried to print screenshots

```
    private void print_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
         printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
         printDocument1.PrinterSettings = ps;

        this.printDocument1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.printDocument1_PrintPage);

        printDocument1.Print();            
   }


    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(),new Point(),new Size(this.Width,this.Height));
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but I am looking for the most suitable form of documents which prints fast and without opening in any of the third party software while printing

Comment: @Sivajith yes,this prints without prompting any dialog,also getting graphics of any image files(bmp/jpg/png etc)should do